# Specifying @SpringBootApplication in @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

Using `@WebMvcTest` will auto-configure all web layer beans by looking for a `@SpringBootConfiguration` class (such as `@SpringBootApplication`).

If the configuration class is in a different package and can't be found by scanning, can I provide it directly to `@WebMvcTest`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will point to the correct `@SpringBootApplication` class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {MyController.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MySpringBootApplicationClass.class})
public class MyControllerTest {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ***@WebMvcTest*** for your test , it means you are focusing mainly on testing the spring mvc layer and not going any deeper into the application.

> So this annotation can be used only when a test ***focuses on Spring
>   MVC components*.** By default, tests annotated with @WebMvcTest will
>   also auto-configure Spring Security and MockMvc (include support for
>   HtmlUnit WebClient and Selenium WebDriver). For more fine-grained
>   control of MockMVC the @AutoConfigureMockMvc annotation can be
>   used.Typically ***@WebMvcTest*** is used in combination with
>   ***@MockBean*** or ***@Import*** to create any collaborators required by your *@Controller* beans.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import({ CustomerConfig.class, SchedulerConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

}
```

You can then import this configuration class using `@import` in the `@WebMvcTest` annotated test class and the beans should be picked up by spring.

Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html